# Nginx - Treats PHP as binary

Tags: php, drupal, binary, download, nginx

We are running Nginx+FastCgi as the backend for our Drupal site.
Everything seems to work like fine, except for this one url.
http:///sites/all/modules/tinymce/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/smimage/index.php

(We use TinyMCE module in Drupal, and the url above is invoked when
user tries to upload an image)

When we were using Apache,  everything was working fine.
However, nginx treats that above url Binary and tries to Download it.
(We've verified that the file pointed out by the url is a valid PHP file)

Any idea what could be wrong here?

I think it's something to do with the NGINX configuration, but not entirely sure what that is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Config:
Here's the snippet from the nginx configuration file:

```
      root /var/www/;
       index index.php;

       if (!-e $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
       }

       error_page 404 index.php;
       location ~*
\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$
{
               deny all;
       }

       location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
             access_log        off;
           expires           7d;
       }

       location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
             access_log        off;
           expires           7d;
       }

       location ~ .php$ {
           include /etc/nginx/fcgi.conf;
           fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
           fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
           fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
           fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
       }

       location ~ /\.ht {
               deny  all;
       }
```

Comment: Did you turn on eAccelerator by any chance? If yes disable it and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

instead of

```
location ~ .php$ {
```

Comment: That'd mean it'd also match files like "foophp", . means "any character", so escaping it to get the "real" . is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't do it, also be sure that you have fastcgi running on port 8888. You can check that with:

```
netstat -la | grep :8888
```

You're okay if you get a response like:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:9000          *:*                     LISTEN
```

Or try the following and look for which port it is listening on:

```
netstat -la | grep LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the php file is running but generating a binary file.  Is this script generating an image?  Hard to tell without seeing some config.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Martin.
We have verified that PHP is not generating an image.

I have updated my post with Config details.